# Rails: Count optional tags while having conditional tags in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, tags, conditional-statements, option-type

I want to find products matching as many **optional tags** as possible which are tagged by all **conditional tags**, ordered by the amount of matching **optional tags**.

I came up with this for counting the **optional tags**:

```
optional_tags = [1,2,3]
conditional_tags = [4]

products = Product.select('COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.*')
                  .joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', optional_tags)
                  .group('products.id')
                  .order('count_all DESC')
```

I successfully get the product ids and the number of matching **optional tags**:

```
products: {30=>4, 26=>3, 29=>3, 27=>2, 28=>1}
```

When I try to add the **conditional tags** I only get an empty hash. I tried it this way:

```
products = Product.where('tags.id IN (?)', conditional_tags)
                  .select('COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.*')
                  .joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', optional_tags)
                  .group('products.id')
                  .order('count_all DESC')
```

Rails optimizes the query and combines all **where** parts...

How could I add the **conditional tags** to my construct? Thanks for any help!

**Example:**

The type of a product is important, but people don't care about the details.

conditional_tags = [**1** *car*]

optional_tags = [**2** *red*, **3** *mercedes*, **4** *fast*]

A *red* **car** would be ok, but a *red fast* **motorcycle** by *mercedes* should not be in the list of results even though there are more matching tags.

Comment: What's the meaning of an optional tag and a conditional tag on a product? Is it possible to explain in less technical terms what you're trying to do?

Comment: **Conditional tags** are _must-haves_ (tags that must be connected to a product to get listed). **Optional tags** are _nice-to-have_. In the end all conditional tags and as many optional tags as possible are the perfect match... I hope that makes it clearer... :/

Comment: The most recent version of my most recent answer might be it. If not, I give up, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, Jason. I think I figured it out... I perform a sub-query for the **conditional tags** within the main query for the **optional tags**.

My Product scopes:

```
scope :tagged, lambda { |tag_ids|
  joins(:tags)
  .where('tags.id IN (?)', tag_ids)
  .group('products.id')
}
scope :matched, lambda { |product_ids, tag_ids|
  select('COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.*')
  .joins(:tags)
  .where('products.id IN (?) AND tags.id IN (?)', product_ids, tag_ids)
  .group('products.id')
  .order('count_all DESC')
}
```

My query construct:

```
result = Product.matched(Product.tagged(branch_ids).map(&:id), tag_ids)
```

I am a little concerned about the performance, because Rails has to perform two separate queries. The nice thing is, that I can add a .limit() to the "main" query.

If someone has an idea how to solve this within one query, please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware, but I think your second query is equivalent to this:

```
products = Product.select('COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.*')
                  .joins(:tags)
                  .where('tags.id IN (?) AND tags.id IN (?)', optional_tags, conditional_tags)
                  .group('products.id')
                  .order('count_all DESC')
```

Maybe you're after something closer to this?

```
products = Product.select('COUNT(*) AS count_all, products.*')
                  .joins(:tags)
                  .where('tags.id IN (?)', optional_tags | conditional_tags)
                  .group('products.id')
                  .order('count_all DESC')
```

My guess is probably not right, since I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. Maybe that gets you a little further down the road, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I finally figured it out:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :having_tags, -> { |tags|
    joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', tags)
  }

  scope :ordered_by_tag_count, -> { |tags|
    joins(:tags)
    .where('tags.id IN (?)', tags)
    .group('products.id')
    .order('count_all DESC')
  }
end
```

So if you have these tags:

> conditional_tags = [1 car]
>
> optional_tags = [2 red, 3 mercedes, 4 fast]

You might do this:

```
Product.having_tags([1]).ordered_by_tag_count([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Actually, this won't work because `.joins` is always a `LEFT JOIN` and never a `JOIN`. Might at least get you closer to a solution, though.

Comment: Basically, I think you need to write one scope that FILTERS by tag, another scope that ORDERS by tag count, and then chain those two scopes, like I did above. The only trick is that each scope has to actually work.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Rails also combines the scopes to one query, so it still fails. Another thing: There are products tagged by [1,2,3] but they don't show up:

`... WHERE (tags.id IN (1)) AND (tags.id IN (2,3)) GROUP BY products.id ORDER BY count_all DESC`